# How to show historical trend in allure report

Tags: java, python, allure

I am not able to figure out, where do I have to put the JSON files in the history folder and how a trend chart will be generated.

My folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - copy the report\history folder in reportmetadata folder.